# Intellij 2018.2 stops working and exits on MacOs. What might be a problem?

Tags: intellij-idea, exit

As an daily IntelliJ user you usually concentrate on the projects you are working on and IntelliJ is just a tool. You are not willing to dig into tool's problem itself. But this is what is forced on you by default after IntelliJ installation on MacOS and opening relatively big project(most of the projects nowadays are huge and have thousands of files and use numbers of IntelliJ 3rd party plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal list of actions. IntelliJ must have set **MORE RAM** to be used by default.

1. Read: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files . 
   From IntelliJ open **Help / Show log in Finder** and open idea.log file with Console.app; In Console.app press "Reload" and "Now" buttons to track "live" what IntelliJ is doing.
2. If in logs of IntelliJ you find that some of the plugins exit with fatal error, you just uninstall those plugins. For me the one that failed to the moment of this answer was "BashSupport" as example.
3. Start Terminal.app ; Run command: `open -a TextEdit /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions` ; Change options in idea.vmoptions file to: 
   `-Xms1024m
   -Xmx2048m` ; Read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html to see how you can tune IntelliJ for your project. This step is handy when your IntelliJ app doesn't start at all and you want to change properties in a **global** way.
4. From IntelliJ open **Help / Edit Custom Properties...**. Here you can set same properties that will **override global** and will work only for current OS user.
5. Also there is also a possibility of underlying OS to do it voodoo magic so the IntelliJ won't work as it should like here - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000398280-IDEA-Ultimate-2018-2-Unable-to-save-settings-Unable-to-create-file-Windows-10
6. Make sure your project build output for *.class files is set. Read: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000000584-Build-does-nothing . In my case when IntelliJ started project build it terminated without warnings shortly after.
7. Finally in my case none of 6 steps above solved the issue so I found this read: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000532044-IntelliJ-cannot-build-projects . Basically try reinstall IntelliJ from original distribution again.

I know that you must read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea every time you install a new version of IntelliJ, but why not to add some consistency into configuration process of the main java process that runs IntelliJ itself? You can ask how much ram to use during installation of IntelliJ and explain why it is so. Then Help digging won't be necessary in the first place for devs who fed up with changing those default settings that will be always more than 700MB. I think for most devs out there it is at least 10x of that. I bet what makes most devs mad about this is not the fact that you need to do some options changing, but where those options are depending on OS plus the fact that you simply forget why IntelliJ app just exits while you are doing a debugging of your own app. I bet this problem makes us mad since first java based IDEs appeared. User-friendly is the key here and explicit reminders within the app itself would help.